# Disable Plotly in Python from communicating with the network in any form

Tags: python, networking, plotly

Is it possible to get Plotly (used from within Python) to be "strictly local"? In other words, is it possible to use it in a way that guarantees it won't contact the network for any reason?

This includes things like the program trying to contact the Plotly service (since that was the business model), and also things like ensuring clicking anywhere in the generated html won't either have a link to Plotly or anywhere else.

Of course, I'd like to be able to do this on a production machine connected to the network, so pulling out the network connection is not an option.

Comment: Have you found a better solution?

Comment: @LauriK not so far.

Answer (score 2):

Even a simple `import plotly` already attempts to connect to the network as this example shows:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
import plotly
```

The output is:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.plot.ly
```

The connection is made when the [get_graph_reference() function](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/22cb9d92bb8485f660aab60cc58ea1791505a097/plotly/graph_reference.py#L66) is called [while the graph_reference module is initialized](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/22cb9d92bb8485f660aab60cc58ea1791505a097/plotly/graph_reference.py#L518).

One way to avoid connecting to plot.ly servers is to set an invalid `plotly_api_domain` in `~/.plotly/.config`. For me, this is not an option as the software is run on the client’s machine and I do not want to modify their configuration file. Additionally, [it is also not yet possible to change the configuration directory through an environment variable](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/533).

One work-around is to monkey-patch `requests.get` before importing plotly:

```
import requests
import inspect
original_get = requests.get

def plotly_no_get(*args, **kwargs):
    one_frame_up = inspect.stack()[1]
    if one_frame_up[3] == 'get_graph_reference':
        raise requests.exceptions.RequestException
    return original_get(*args, **kwargs)

requests.get = plotly_no_get
import plotly
```

This is surely not a full solution but, if nothing else, this shows that plot.ly is currently not meant to be run completely offline.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have come up with a solution for this. First, you need download the open source Plotly.js [file](https://plot.ly/javascript/getting-started/). Then I have a function, written below, that will produce the javascript from the python plot and reference your local copy of plotly-latest.min.js. See below:

```
import sys
import os
from plotly import session, tools, utils
import uuid
import json

def get_plotlyjs():
    path = os.path.join('offline', 'plotly.min.js')
    plotlyjs = resource_string('plotly', path).decode('utf-8')
    return plotlyjs


def js_convert(figure_or_data,outfilename, show_link=False, link_text='Export to plot.ly',
          validate=True):

    figure = tools.return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate)

    width = figure.get('layout', {}).get('width', '100%')
    height = figure.get('layout', {}).get('height', 525)
    try:
        float(width)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        pass
    else:
        width = str(width) + 'px'

    try:
        float(width)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        pass
    else:
        width = str(width) + 'px'

    plotdivid = uuid.uuid4()
    jdata = json.dumps(figure.get('data', []), cls=utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    jlayout = json.dumps(figure.get('layout', {}), cls=utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

    config = {}
    config['showLink'] = show_link
    config['linkText'] = link_text
    config["displaylogo"]=False
    config["modeBarButtonsToRemove"]= ['sendDataToCloud']
    jconfig = json.dumps(config)

    plotly_platform_url = session.get_session_config().get('plotly_domain',
                                                           'https://plot.ly')
    if (plotly_platform_url != 'https://plot.ly' and
            link_text == 'Export to plot.ly'):

        link_domain = plotly_platform_url\
            .replace('https://', '')\
            .replace('http://', '')
        link_text = link_text.replace('plot.ly', link_domain)


    script = '\n'.join([
        'Plotly.plot("{id}", {data}, {layout}, {config}).then(function() {{',
        '    $(".{id}.loading").remove();',
        '}})'
    ]).format(id=plotdivid,
              data=jdata,
              layout=jlayout,
              config=jconfig)

    html="""<div class="{id} loading" style="color: rgb(50,50,50);">
                 Drawing...</div>
                 <div id="{id}" style="height: {height}; width: {width};" 
                 class="plotly-graph-div">
                 </div>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                 {script}
                 </script>
                 """.format(id=plotdivid, script=script,
                           height=height, width=width)

    #html =  html.replace('\n', '')
    with open(outfilename, 'wb') as out:
        #out.write(r'<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>')
        out.write(r'<script src="plotly-latest.min.js"></script>')
        for line in html.split('\n'):
            out.write(line)

        out.close()
    print ('JS Conversion Complete')
```

The key lines that takes away all the links are:

```
config['showLink'] = show_link #False
....
config["modeBarButtonsToRemove"]= ['sendDataToCloud']
```

You would call the fuction as such to get a static HTML file that references your local copy of plotly open-sourced library:

```
fig = {
"data": [{
    "x": [1, 2, 3],
    "y": [4, 2, 5]
}],
"layout": {
    "title": "hello world"
}
}
js_convert(fig, 'test.html')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. My purpose in asking the question was primarily to see if there was an inbuilt API to avoid any network communication, or even a "turn-off network access" mechanism by for eg, not importing a module that would perform network communication. The reason is to ensure confidential data does not leak. Your answer provides a way to get it to work with local links, which is valuable but doesn't quite offer that guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any extensive testing, but it looks like Plot.ly offers an "offline" mode:

https://plot.ly/python/offline/

A simple example:

```
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter

plot([Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[3, 1, 6])])
```

You can install Plot.ly via `pip` and then run the above script to produce a static HTML file:

```
$ pip install plotly
$ python ./above_script.py
```

When I run this from Terminal my web browser opens to the following file URL:

```
file:///some/path/to/temp-plot.html
```

This renders an interact graph that is completely local to your file system.